# How to await a Microsoft speechrecognizer async function and store the text into a variable from the callback - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, azure-cognitive-services

```
const fs = require("fs");
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");

// This example requires environment variables named "SPEECH_KEY" and "SPEECH_REGION"
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(process.env.SPEECH_KEY, process.env.SPEECH_REGION);
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

async function fromFile() {
    let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync("YourAudioFile.wav"));
    let speechRecognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    let outputText = "";
    speechRecognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
        switch (result.reason) {
            case sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                outputText = `RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`;
                break;
            case sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
                outputText = "NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.";
                break;
            case sdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
                const cancellation = sdk.CancellationDetails.fromResult(result);
                outputText = `CANCELED: Reason=${cancellation.reason}`;

                if (cancellation.reason == sdk.CancellationReason.Error) {
                    outputText = `CANCELED: ErrorCode=${cancellation.ErrorCode}`;
                    outputText = `CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${cancellation.errorDetails}`;
                    outputText = "CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?";
                }
                break;
        }
        speechRecognizer.close();
    });
   return outputText;
}

let responseMsg = await fromFile();
console.log(responseMsg);
```

I'm trying to store the result from an async speechrecognizer method's callback. Inspite of adding async await keys, I'm unable to do that. The last console.log statements executes before the speechrecognizer method is completed.

I'm new to JS and I'm still in the learning phase for callbacks, promises,etc.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the async/await version instead of callback

```
async function fromFile() {
    let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync("YourAudioFile.wav"));
    let speechRecognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    let outputText = "";
    const result = await recognize(speechRecognizer);

    switch (result.reason) {
            case sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                outputText = `RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`;
                break;
            case sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
                outputText = "NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.";
                break;
            case sdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
                const cancellation = sdk.CancellationDetails.fromResult(result);
                outputText = `CANCELED: Reason=${cancellation.reason}`;

                if (cancellation.reason == sdk.CancellationReason.Error) {
                    outputText = `CANCELED: ErrorCode=${cancellation.ErrorCode}`;
                    outputText = `CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${cancellation.errorDetails}`;
                    outputText = "CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?";
                }
                break;
   }

   speechRecognizer.close();
   return outputText;
}

async function recognize(speechRecognizer) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        speechRecognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
            resolve(result);
        }, err => {
            reject(err);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this and received an error. The await key before speechRecognizer.recognizeOnceAsync has no effect. Switch case threw an error "result.reason" is undefined.

Comment: According to the documentation, they don't support async function. So we must implement our async version. Please checked my edited answer

Comment: Understood the usage of Promise here. Thank you